# Fragment Static CheckBox NullPointer Exception in MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Why can I not access a static checkbox object?

**MainActivity** (Where I want to call it)

```
if (color == 0) {
    ColorFragment.yellow.setChecked(true);
}
...
```

**ColorFragment** (Where it is initialized)

```
static RadioButton yellow;

yellow = (RadioButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.yellow_button);
```

I've tried adding `getApplicationContext(), getActivity()` and others to `getView()` with no luck.

Why is it causing this `NullPointerException`?

Comment: make sure `ColorFragment` executing after attaching `ColorFragment` to Main Activity?

Comment: Good idea, but even with it clearly set after the viewpager is setup, it still give a NullPointer.

Comment: what is position of `ColorFragment` in ViewPager?

Comment: I am using TabHost to add a view pager to add the ColorFragment to the view pager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Problem**

The variable `yellow` is returning `null` because it is instantiated after I am trying to call it.

---

**The Solution**

I looked for the value of the `static` variable `MainActivity.color` in the `onActivityCreated` method of `ColorFragment`.

I used a `switch` and `case` to `setChecked()` as well.

```
switch (MainActivity.color) {
    case 0:
        yellow.setChecked(true);
        break;
    case 1:
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can most certainly access your static RadioButton yellow member variable from outside of your ColorFragment class.

The problem lies with the point at which this member variable is initialized to something non-null.  Since you lazy initialize this member variable, there are a few things to watch out for:

1) You must make sure to only access ColorFragment.yellow after your ColorFragment's onCreateView method is called, or make sure to check for null so you don't crash with a NullPointerException if your ColorFragment has not yet had its onCreateView method called.

AND

2) Make sure you really have a RadioButton with the id yellow_button declared inside of the layout that your ColorFragment inflates as its content view.  If you don't, findViewById(R.id.yellow_button) returns null, which in turn sets yellow to null, and you will run the risk of a NullPointerException.

Comment: You are very right. It was returning null.

I changed the way I was looking for the object with an if statement and fixed it.